How to get a response as an object (Key value pair) in GCP Bigquery
Is there a function or method available to obtain a response in the form of an object key-value pair? I've currently achieved this by concatenating, but it's time-consuming for large datasets. Additionally, the input may consist of over a 5000 CRN numbers at once.
Expected Output:
    {crn_no:{associated data with that no}}

eg: {
        "20035A": {
            "MOVEMENT": "REGISTRATION",
            "REASON": "DISMISSAL",
            "STATUS": "CLOSED",
        },
        "220022F": {
            "MOVEMENT": "REGISTRATION",
            "REASON": null,
            "STATUS": "OPEN",
        }
}

I Tried several methods but was not able so did it with concatenating which is generating in string format and consumes a lot of time.
Is there any other approach known to anybody which can achieve the output. Please assist.
NOT GETTING result as Expected:
WITH crn_data AS (
  SELECT crn_number,
        STATUS,
        MOVEMENT,
        STATUS,
FROM 
  table.view_name
WHERE 
    crn_number IN UNNEST(@crnNo)
)

WITH crn_data AS (
  SELECT crn_number,
     STRUCT(  
       STATUS,
       MOVEMENT,
       STATUS
    ) AS crn_details
  FROM table.view_name
  WHERE crn_number IN UNNEST(@crnNo)
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING( 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT crn_number, claim_details FROM crn_data)
) AS json_output;

Concatenating working query:
WITH crn_data AS (
  SELECT 
    crn_number,
    TO_JSON_STRING(
      STRUCT(
        STATUS,
        REASON,
        STATUS,
      )
    ) AS json_data
  FROM
    table.view_name
  WHERE
    crn_number IN UNNEST(@crnNo)
)

SELECT CONCAT("{", STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', crn_number, '":', json_data), ","), "}") AS result
FROM crn_data;

